# How can I find the keys of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, key

I know in JavaScript, *objects* double as hashes, but I have been unable to find a built-in function to get the keys:

```
var h = {a:'b', c:'d'};
```

I want something like

```
var k = h.keys() ; // k = ['a', 'c'];
```

It is simple to write a function myself to iterate over the items and add the keys to an array that I return, but is there a standard cleaner way to do that?

I keep feeling it must be a simple built in function that I missed but I can't find it!

Comment: I'm just jumping into javascript but this post may help you. http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/07/enum/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array of object's keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Comment: What about getting the values from the keys? Also, getting the number of keys in a hash.

Comment: The 2017 answer:
Object.keys(h)
Object.values(h)

Answer (score 290, accepted):

There is function in modern JavaScript (ECMAScript 5) called [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) performing this operation:

```
var obj = { "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3};
alert(Object.keys(obj)); // will output ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Compatibility details can be found [here](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

On the [Mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) there is also a snippet for backward compatibility:

```
if(!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o){
   if (o !== Object(o))
      throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
   var ret=[],p;
   for(p in o) if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) ret.push(p);
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this have been more natural? `if(!Object.prototype.keys) Object.prototype.keys = function() {
   if (this !== Object(this))
      throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
   var ret = [], p;
   for (p in this) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, p)) ret.push(p);
   return ret;
}
var x = { a: { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3 }, b: { A: 10, B: 20 } };
alert(x.a.keys());`

Comment: As I understand this `Object.prototype.keys` will make `keys` available to all sub-classes of Object, therefore for all objects. Which probably you want to if you're trying to use OOP. Anyway this really depends on your requirements.

Comment: If you use mootools, Object.keys() should be available in all browsers.

Comment: Is there anything to use this in angular templates? Its not working there inside partials.

Comment: I think you should ask this as separate question with code sample.

Answer (score 82):

For production code requiring a large compatibility with client browsers I still suggest [Ivan Nevostruev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912/how-can-i-find-the-keys-of-a-hash/6921193#6921193) with shim to ensure `Object.keys` in older browsers. However, it's possible to get the exact functionality requested using ECMA's new `defineProperty` feature.

**As of ECMAScript 5 - Object.defineProperty**

As of ECMA5 you can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define non-enumerable properties. The [**current compatibility**](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#test-Object.defineProperty) still has much to be desired, but this should eventually become usable in all browsers. (Specifically note the current incompatibility with IE8!)

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'keys', {
  value: function keys() {
    var keys = [];
    for(var i in this) if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      keys.push(i);
    }
    return keys;
  },
  enumerable: false
});

var o = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
}

for (var k in o) {
    console.log(k, o[k])
}

console.log(o.keys())

# OUTPUT
# > a 1
# > b 2
# > ["a", "b"]
```

However, since ECMA5 already added `Object.keys` you might as well use:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'keys', {
  value: function keys() {
    return Object.keys(this);
  },
  enumerable: false
});
```

**Original answer**

```
Object.prototype.keys = function ()
{
  var keys = [];
  for(var i in this) if (this.hasOwnProperty(i))
  {
    keys.push(i);
  }
  return keys;
}
```

---

**Edit:** Since this answer has been around for a while I'll leave the above untouched. Anyone reading this should also read Ivan Nevostruev's answer below.

There's no way of making prototype functions non-enumerable which leads to them always turning up in for-in loops that don't use `hasOwnProperty`. I still think this answer would be ideal if extending the prototype of Object wasn't so messy.

Comment: 'hasOwnProperty' excludes properties on the prototypes of this object, which is useful to know.

Comment: Answer accepted because that's how I ended up implementing it but I feel this should have been a built-in function of the language.

Comment: Note that you should use "for (var i in this)..." to avoid creating a global variable.

Comment: I'd avoid modifying Object.prototype - as another commenter noted below, this can easily break scripts which aren't careful about checking hasOwnProperty().  Instead, use the less OO-friendly way: define a 'keys' function if it doesn't already exist.  (Firefox and Chrome both implement a native keys() function which does exactly what the OP wants - IE does not)

Comment: There isn't a `Object.prototype.keys` in ECMAScript 5. https://gist.github.com/1034464

Comment: It seems to be a bad idea to add anything to Object.prototype, as it breaks every normal loop like:  for (var k in array) { }  or  for (var k in object), and that idiom - though it might be faulty - is extremely common.  For example according to Matthew Darwin's answer below, it breaks Google Maps.

Comment: This is not the way to go for a number of reasons; 1) You really shouldn't be adding things to `Object.prototype` at all, and certainly not this way 2) You should be using `Object.keys` as mentioned in Ivan Nevostuev's answer

Comment: @OliverNightingale I'm not sure how to take your comment. I already say the same thing in the *Edit* part of my answer.

Answer (score 45):

You can use `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(h)
```

Comment: Added in ECMAScript 5 but should work in most major browsers by now

Answer (score 33):

You could use [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#keys), which is a JavaScript utility library.

```
_.keys({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3});
// => ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: Well, it's not really what was asked, because @Pat is looking for a built-in function, but it's an interesting library nonetheless, and it does not modify `Object.prototype`

Comment: These days, I think it is much more helpful to use these nifty little library-lets than go on writing your own implementations...

Anyways, in most real-world projects, we are anyways using Underscore or equivalent libraries.
Personally, I'd rather go with Underscore.

Comment: `_.keys(obj).length` to see if there are any keys.

Answer (score 14):

This is the best you can do, as far as I know...

```
var keys = [];
for (var k in h)keys.push(k);
```

Comment: This also doesn't work when Object.prototype has been messed with.

Comment: It would be better to use this, and not to "mess with" Object.prototype.  It seems that everything breaks if we add things to Object.prototype: it is an extremely common idiom to loop over the keys of an array / object.

Answer (score 8):

Using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), you can get the keys like this:

```
var bobject =  {primary:"red", bg:"maroon", hilite:"green"};
var keys = [];
$.each(bobject, function(key, val){ keys.push(key); });
console.log(keys); // ["primary", "bg", "hilite"]
```

Or:

```
var bobject =  {primary:"red", bg:"maroon", hilite:"green"};
$.map(bobject, function(v, k){return k;});
```

Thanks to @pimlottc.

Comment: If you wanted to go this route, you might as well use `JQuery.map`:

    `$.map(h, function(v,k) { return k; });`

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can loop through the properties of the object using for/in, so you could do something like this:

```
function getKeys(h) {
  Array keys = new Array();
  for (var key in h)
    keys.push(key);
  return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to use [AnnanFay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912/how-can-i-find-the-keys-of-a-hash/18941#18941):

```
Object.prototype.keys = function () ...
```

However, when using it in conjunction with the [Google Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) API v3, Google Maps is non-functional.

However,

```
for (var key in h) ...
```

works well.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript we can use

```
Object.keys(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the elements only, but not the functions then this code can help you:

```
this.getKeys = function() {

    var keys = new Array();
    for (var key in this) {

        if (typeof this[key] !== 'function') {

            keys.push(key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

This is part of my implementation of the HashMap and I only want the keys. `this` is the hashmap object that contains the keys.