# How to get values from key/value array in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON string.

```js
var obj = {"cities":[{"city_name":"abc"},{"city_name":"xyz"}]}
```

How can I get the values for the key `city_name`, using JavaScript or JQuery, and get another array like:

```js
["abc","xyz"]
```

I tried many ways but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hash keys / values as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415133/hash-keys-values-as-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var obj = {"cities":[{"city_name":"abc"},{"city_name":"xyz"}]}
var result = obj.cities.map(function (el) {
   return el.city_name;
});
console.log(result);
```

if you use `ES2015` you can also use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  with [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var result = obj.cities.map(el => el.city_name);
```

[`Example`](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iky7q3ct/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexander . It made things so easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like:

```
var newObj = [];
$.each(obj.cities,function(k,v){
  newObj.push(v.city_name);
});
console.log(newObj);
```