# How can I get a collection of keys in a JavaScript dictionary?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
var driversCounter = {
    "one":   1,
    "two":   2,
    "three": 3,
    "four":  4,
    "five":  5
}
```

Now, I need to show it in a dropdownlist. How can I get the collection of keys in my dictionary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [*shim*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatiblity) it in older browsers...

```
const keys = Object.keys(driversCounter);
```

If you wanted *values*, there is [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and if you want key *and* value, you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), often paired with `Array.prototype.forEach()` like this...

```
Object.entries(driversCounter).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   console.log(key, value);
});
```

---

Alternatively, considering your use case, maybe this will do it...

```
var selectBox, option, prop;

selectBox = document.getElementById("drivers");

for (prop in driversCounter) {
   option = document.createElement("option");
   option.textContent = prop;
   option.value = driversCounter[prop];
   selectBox.add(option);
}
```

Comment: `dict.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Answer (score 74):

One option is using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(driversCounter)
```

It works fine for modern browsers (however, Internet Explorer supports it starting from [version 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) only).

To add compatible support you can copy the code snippet provided in **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**.

Answer (score 21):

To loop through the "dictionary" (we call it object in JavaScript), use a `for in` loop:

```js
for(var key in driversCounter) {
    if(driversCounter.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // key                 = keys,  left of the ":"
        // driversCounter[key] = value, right of the ":"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This will work in all JavaScript implementations:

```
var keys = [];

for (var key in driversCounter) {
    if (driversCounter.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
}
```

Like others mentioned before you may use `Object.keys`, but it may not work in older engines. So you can use the following monkey patch:

```
if (!Object.keys) {
    Object.keys = function (object) {
        var keys = [];

        for (var key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys.push(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply use `Object.keys()`:

```js
var driversCounter = {
                      "one": 1,
                      "two": 2,
                      "three": 3,
                      "four": 4,
                      "five": 5
                     }
console.log(Object.keys(driversCounter));
```

Comment: How is that different from previous answers?

Answer (score 5):

With a modern JavaScript engine you can use `Object.keys(driversCounter)`.

Answer (score 4):

For new browsers: `Object.keys( MY_DICTIONARY )` will return an array of keys. Else you may want to go the old school way:

```
var keys = []
for(var key in dic) keys.push( key );
```

Comment: Incomplete due to possible prototyping.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you *could* use `Object.keys()`, but who cares about older browsers, right?

Well, I do.

Try [this](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_keys:324). `array_keys` from PHPJS *ports* PHP's handy `array_keys` function, so it can be used in JavaScript.

At a glance, it uses `Object.keys` if supported, but it handles the case where it isn't very easily. It even includes filtering the keys based on values you might be looking for (optional) and a toggle for whether or not to use strict comparison `===` versus typecasting comparison `==` (optional).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery then

```
var keys = [];
$.each(driversCounter, function(key, value) {
    keys.push(key);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(keys));
```

Here follows the answer:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

And this way you wouldn't have to worry if the browser supports the `Object.keys` method or not.

Answer (score -5):

A different approach would be to using multi-dimensional arrays:

```
var driversCounter = [
    ["one", 1], 
    ["two", 2], 
    ["three", 3], 
    ["four", 4], 
    ["five", 5]
]
```

and access the value by driverCounter[k][j], where j=0,1 in the case.

Add it in a drop down list by:

```
var dd = document.getElementById('your_dropdown_element');
for(i=0;i<driversCounter.length-1;i++)
{
    dd.options.add(opt);
    opt.text = driversCounter[i][0];
    opt.value = driversCounter[i][1];
}
```