# JQuery - How i can compare two list

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one list and one DOM Object i need compare and get different value theirs

**Example:**

```
lista1 = ["type", "name","visible"] 
lista2 = Object {type: "button", name: "button", class: "buttonBlack", visible: "true", backgroundimage: "null"}

lista2 = Object.keys(list2);
```

i try:

```
for(var i = 0; i<lista1.length;i++)

    $.each(lista2,function(key,val){
        if(lista[i] == val){
         list2.remove(val);
        }      
    });
};
```

I want to get the items that are not equal between them

How can i make this ?

**expected return:**

```
["class","backgroundimage"]
```

Comment: Are you trying to find out if a key from array `list1` is missing from hash `list2`?

Comment: are lista1, lista2 lista, list2 completely different items or are they typos in your naming convention.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to do. Please provide more information.

Comment: @Mgamba I want to get the items that are not equal between them

Comment: but none are equal here

Comment: `i need compare and get different value theirs` What does this mean?

Comment: @user2403131: Yeah, that doesn't make sense. You are comparing two completely different things (an array and an object). How can they be "equal". Do you mean what mgamba said?

Comment: And please clarify your variable names. You have `list1`, `list2`, `lista1`, `lista2` and `lista`. Only `list1` and `list2` are defined.

Comment: @Matt burland I need to compare is the key object

Comment: but you are using several different variables and we dont know what they are, expand on what each variable actually contains.

Comment: Your result is just keys in `lista2` that are not in the array `lista1`. Do you also want values from `lista1` that are not keys in `lista2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = ["type", "name","visible"] 
list2 = {type: "button", name: "button", class: "buttonBlack", visible: "true", backgroundimage: "null"}
result = []

$.each(list2, function(k,v){
  if ($.inArray(k, list1) === -1) {
    result.push(k)
  }
})

result
>> ["class", "backgroundimage"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list1 = ["type", "name", "class", "visible", "backgroundimage", "disabled", "value"];
var list2 = {type: "button", name: "button", class: "buttonBlack", visible: "true", backgroundimage: "null"};

list2 = Object.keys(list2);

function arr_diff(a1, a2)
{
  var a=[], diff=[];
  for(var i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
    a[a1[i]]=true;
  for(var i=0;i<a2.length;i++)
    if(a[a2[i]]) delete a[a2[i]];
    else a[a2[i]]=true;
  for(var k in a)
    diff.push(k);
  return diff;
}

console.log(arr_diff(list1, list2));
```

results in

```
["disabled", "value"]
```

** *based on*
[Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)
[JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tTFE/)

Comment: `a` is being treated as an object but is defined as an array.

Comment: I need the left over from list2   list of key

Answer (score 0):

```
lista1 = ["type", "name","visible"] 
lista2 = Object {type: "button", name: "button", class: "buttonBlack", visible: "true", backgroundimage: "null"}

result = [];

for (var prop in lista2) {
   if (lista2.hasOwnProperty(prop) && lista1.indexOf(prop) < 0) {
       result.push(prop);
   }
}
```

The array `result` will contain all the properties of the object that aren't in your array.