# Shorthand to loop over just keys of an Object?

Tags: javascript, loops, lodash

I know (with Lodash or vanilla JS) how to loop generally over an object and get the keys and values. `_.forOwn()` and `_.forEach()`, etc.

My question is if there is a way to only loop through the keys in a neat shorthand. In other words, can I simplify this code:

```
_.forEach(myObject, (value, key) => {
 // do something quick and important that only needs key
)}
```

I don't need the `value`, only the `key`, and so I'm wondering if there's a shorthand to just go through the keys.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys

Comment: Is `for (const key of Object.keys(myObject)) { /* Do stuff with key */ }` what you're looking for?

Comment: might depend on the "quick and important that only needs key"

Comment: @KevinB I don't think it's a duplicate of that one, as I read through that. Just want to iterate over the keys of an object without reference to the values. Creating an array first would, sure, do it, but I'm looking for something quicker.

Comment: @CRice that's getting closer.

Comment: quicker... or shorter/simpler. how is CRice's example any different from what i suggested paired with a loop? (it's identical)

Comment: Looking for shorter/simpler code. Doesn't have to beat native JS in milliseconds.

Comment: Nothing is going to be shorter than what you have.

Comment: So there has to be a reference to the `values`, even if I don't need them?

Comment: Yes, unless you create your own iteration method that does it without. but it's still no shorter if you count the code needed to create said iteration method. that includes anything you could do with a library.

Comment: You can as stated use Object.keys to get an array of keys and loop over that, but... it's probably not much better.

Comment: The best you could do (afaik) is something like `Object.keys(myObject).forEach(someFunctionThatTakesAKey)`. It's not going to get much shorter than that. But I'm not sure why you'd like to get it so succinct? What about `Object.keys` isn't sufficient for your needs?

Comment: OK, I'm satisfied then, and I already had the simplest iterative method. I'll mark the answer below as good enough. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no shorthand to provide keys AND loop over them. You could write your own utility method, but essentially you can use `Object.keys` or `_.keys` and then `.forEach` over those results.

With plain JavaScript, you can achieve this with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), so no LoDash required.

LoDash provides a [`_.keys` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keys).

Comment: It provides keys indeed, but does not loop over it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `_.keys()`. Not exactly what I want. I know how to do it this way, just was curious if someone knew of something quicker and shorter.