# What is array besides string/arrays?

Tags: javascript

Trying to learn javascript by reading [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) sourcecode and came across the below code:

```js
var shallowProperty = function(key) {
  return function(obj) {
    return obj == null ? void 0 : obj[key];
  };
};

var getLength = shallowProperty('length');

console.log(getLength('123'))//3
console.log('123'['length'])//3

console.log(getLength(['1','2']))//2
console.log(['1','2']['length'])//2
```

My question is, what is `[length]` besides `['1','2']`? Any technical terms to call it? Where can we get the full list of keys/attributes available other than `length`?

Comment: I can't seem to find `console.log(['1','2']['length'])` in the page you hyperlinked. Can you send me a link to the actual page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Comment: Why learn JavaScript by studying a one off version of the language? Syntax, methods, properties, etc. might be slightly different or not even exist in JavaScript. You'll start getting confused and ask questions like: *"Any technical terms to call it?"*

Comment: @zer00ne: Having comments beside every sections of code can really help a total newbie like me very much. Or there is any other better recommendations?

Comment: Yes there is, sir. [https://javascript.info](https://javascript.info) is current and designed for n00bs. I glanced at what you are studying and I got dizzy o_O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is a JavaScript object. An object can have `properties`. You can access them in a few, equivalent ways:

```
myObject.property
myObject['property']
```

See this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

To show all the properties of an object:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject);
```

You might like to refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object) about listing the properties of an object.

Comment: Maybe I was just overcomplicated when trying to understand the syntax..

Comment: JavaScript is confusing sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following `object`:

```js
let person = {
  name: 'foo',
  age: 23
}

// Then, there are two possible ways to get the properties of "person" object

console.log(person.name); // logs 'foo'
console.log(person['name']); // logs 'foo'
```