# Parse Json array push javascript

Tags: javascript, push, splice

I have Json Parse list which need to push each category list.
example :

```
    listChartPeriods={"2018-05-04":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-11":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-18":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-25":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-06-01":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442]}
  var categoryData = [];
  var values = [];
  for(var i=0;i<listChartPeriods.length;i++){
      categoryData.push(listChartPeriods.slice(0,1)[0]); //here need to push each date  
      values.push(listChartPeriods[i])
   }
```

**expected out put:**

`categoryData=["2018-05-04","2018-05-11","2018-05-18","2018-05-25","2018-06-01"]`

```
 values=[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442]//each category values
```

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Comment: There isn't any JSON in the code you posted. [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. All you have there is an object whose properties are arrays. No JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Object.keys` to get the dates in the array.

```js
const listChartPeriods={"2018-05-04":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-11":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-18":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-25":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-06-01":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442]}
var categoryData = Object.keys(listChartPeriods);
console.log(categoryData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Below should get the job done for you. A for in loop is your friend when it comes to working with objects.

```js
var listChartPeriods={"2018-05-04":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-11":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-18":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-05-25":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442],"2018-06-01":[21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442,21807210.5028442]}
var categoryData = [];

for(var char in listChartPeriods){
 for(var i = 0; i < listChartPeriods[char].length; i++){
  categoryData.push(listChartPeriods[char][i]);
 }
}
console.log(categoryData);
```

EDIT: Just read your updated question and you are only wanting the key names. You can also do this with a for in loop.

```js
for(var char in listChartPeriods){
 categoryData.push(char)
}
console.log(categoryData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution:

```
 for (let date in listChartPeriods){
    categoryData.push(date);
    let [first] = listChartPeriods[date];
    values.push(first);
 }
```

categoryData = ["2018-05-04", "2018-05-11", "2018-05-18", "2018-05-25", "2018-06-01"]

values = [21807210.5028442, 21807210.5028442, 21807210.5028442, 21807210.5028442, 21807210.5028442]