# Map showing the keys, not only the values

Tags: javascript

If I have this object:

```
const json = {
  products: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Chair Roby",
      style: "Leather",
      color: "red",
    }
  ]
};
```

I can map over the array inside of it and show all the items in the object inside the array like this:

```
const prod = json.products.map(item => {
  return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          {item.name}
        </li>
        <li>
          {item.style}
        </li>
         <li>
          {item.color}
        </li>
      </ul>
  );
});
```

This listed me the values, but how could I show also the keys such as name, style and color?

Comment: what do you mean with "keys" word

Comment: For example in the property color: "red". Key is color and value is red. How can I access the color?

Comment: Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another nested map over the `Object.entries` of each item:

```js
const json = {
  products: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Chair Roby",
      style: "Leather",
      color: "red",
    },
    {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};

class MyList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return json.products.map((obj) => (
      <ul>
        { 
          Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => (
            <li>
              {('key: ' + key +  ', val: ' + val)}
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    ));
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyList />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best aproach is this:

`const prod = Object.keys(json.products).forEach(productKey => {
    return ( <ul> <li> {productKey} - {json.products[productKey]} </li> </ul> );
});`

Comment: But `forEach` returns `undefined`, the JSX you've calculated there gets discarded

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Object.keys(json).map(Followed by necessary code)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const prod = json.products.map(item =>
      <ul>
          {Object.entries(item).map((key, value) =>
             <li>{key}: {value}</li>
          }
      </ul>
);
```