# How to use Promise.all iterate over object keys

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

I am writing in typescript and I have an object with distinct keys, each mapping to a value. I want to iterate over the keys and do an asynchronous function with their value. I know that you can encase .map (to iterate over arrays) in Promise.all, but how can you do it iterating over a for (let i in object) loop? I'm open to other options that allow all keys to be run concurrently, but waiting on all to complete.
Edit: I don't want to use Object.keys because I don't want to iterate over the entire objects keys more than once (Object.keys iterates over the objects keys once, and then I will have to iterate for Promise.all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Comment: Take the object's keys (or values or whatever) and map each to a Promise, then you can call `Promise.all`

Comment: In terms of performance, the object could be very long and I don't want to turn it into an array then iterate over the array.

Comment: You could use `for..in` and push each promise generated from each key to an array, but I'd think that `.map` would be more performant (and, more importantly, much more readable)

Comment: Turning each into a promise isn't good for performance since I have to iterate over the entire object, I'm trying to avoid doing so.

Comment: You say you have to *do an asynchronous function with their value*, so it sounds like there's no avoiding that

Comment: I see your point. I thought when you run promise.all, each iteration runs concurrently, but I guess I misunderstood

Comment: Almost nothing *blocks* by default. Everything will run concurrently unless you explicitly wait for something else to complete first.

Comment: Yea, I wanted to wait on all the promises to complete though, so I was using await Promise.all. In terms of mapping each key to a promise, how would I be able to do that? would it just be array['key'] = new Promise(resolve, reject => {}) and then doing promise.all(array)? Something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202302/discussion-between-vikram-khemlani-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) can get the keys and values. Collect promises for each key-value pair, and fulfill them with `all()`.

```
function asyncFunctionWithKeysAndValuesOf(object) {
  let promises = Object.entries(object).map(keyValue => somePromiseReturningFn(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]))
  return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

If you're sensitive to iterating the object more than once...

```
  let promises = []
  for (key in object) {
    promises.push(somePromiseReturningFn(key, object[key]))
  }
  return Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need the keys and the values, and for performance, I didn't want to use Object. because I didn't want to iterate over the object items more than once.

Comment: @VikramKhemlani, Same idea, using object.entries.  See edit

Comment: Ok . Object.entries iterates over the object once, which is something I was trying to avoid, as map will iterate over the object again, but I guess O(2n) isn't so bad and I don't see a way around it. Thanks

Comment: Agree, @VikramKhemlani, that it's typically fine to loop twice, but we can do just one loop if you prefer.  Just not as pretty. See edit.

Comment: Thanks much! Just fairly new and wanted to make as efficient as possible

Comment: This looks beautiful, but I can't understand it! Maybe giving an example for `somePromiseReturningFn`

Comment: @godhar - I just mean anything that runs asynchronously, like a fetch. The idea behind the post is that sometimes objects hold the parameters that you want to use to call an async function, sort of like an async todo list. This pattern maps the those params into a list of promises (and runs them all with promise all)

Comment: What if I have ids, I Object.entries seems to be using indexes. I need to map an id to a request url. Is this possible?

Comment: Very possible, @godhar.  Object entries provides an array of an object's keys and values. Those might look like indexes if the object is an array. Feel free to write a question and paste the link here.

Comment: Thanks, any help would be really apprecitated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564449/mapping-ids-to-promise-all-response-data