# Mapping ids to Promise.all response data

Tags: typescript, promise, fetch

I have the following which returns a bunch of promises however the returned Promises are not mapped to the utteranceId, as I wished.  I need to keep the ids for my returned data.
Even if I finally wrap my object in `Object.entries(utteranceObject)`

If I log `keyValue` after `Object.entries(utteranceObject).map(keyValue)`

The data looks to be in the correct format `[id, url]´, how should it look when passing to` Promise.all()`?

```
const getUtterancesAudio = async (
 utterances: { utteranceId: string, interviewId: string }[]): Promise<void> => {
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const mapped = utterances.map((u) => {
return { id: u.utteranceId, url: `${config.public.apiBase}/utterance/182bd8fe-f57d- 
4595-b8d7-649ff8ca6d62/interview/665a799a-883b-4b20-9460-3eee486516a8/audio` };
});

const flatten = mapped.map(Object.values);
const forPromisesEntries = Object.fromEntries(flatten);
const getResults = await createPromises(forPromisesEntries);
};



const createPromises = async (utteranceObject: Record<string, string>): 
 Promise<unknown> => {
 const promises = Object.entries(utteranceObject).map(keyValue => 

 buildAudioFetchRequests(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]));

   return Promise.all(promises);
};


const buildAudioFetchRequests = async (key: string, url: string): Promise<unknown> => 
{
 return [key, useAuthenticatedFetch(url, { initialCache: false }]);
};
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(mapped.map(Object.values))` doesn't make much sense - if you want to map the utterances to tuples, you should do that directly, not create an object with id and url.

Comment: Why do you use `Object.fromEntries` before passing the object to `createPromises`, which as first step does `Object.entries` on the argument again? Pass the array of objects (`mapped`) directly!

Comment: "*The data looks to be in the correct format `[id, url]`*" - no it's not. `promises` is an array of promises, and that's actually what `Promise.all` expects. Remove all the extra unnecessary mapping from and to objects, just write code that builds the array of promises. "*I need to keep the ids for my returned data*" - then that is about the result type of the promises. It's the return type of `buildAudioFetchRequests` - do not use `unknown` there! Build tuples there, then call `Object.entries` **after** awaiting the `Promise.all(promises)`.

Comment: Yeah your right, just pass the array and not map it to an Object again. Now only the `Promise.all()` is giving me trouble. I would really appreciate your advice on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565408/types-for-promise-all)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code can be simplified significantly. As I understand it, the OP begins with an array of utterance ids of the form:

```
[ { utteranceId: '123' }, { utteranceId: '456' }, ...
```

and would like produce a result like this:

```
[ { id: '123', result: 'result of api call for 123' }, ...
```

First, build a function that produces the object you want, calling the api and binding the result with the input param, like this...

```
const fetchUtterance = async (id: string, url:string):Promise<unknown> => {
  let response = await useAuthenticatedFetch(url, { initialCache: false });
  return { id, response };  // this is the important part
}
```

Nothing fancy to call it, just map over the utterance ids, producing an array of promises returned by `fetchUtterance()`.  Await those `all()`...

```
const getUtterancesAudio = async (utterances) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  const basePath = '/utterance/182bd8fe-f57d-4595-b8d7-649ff8ca6d62/interview/665a799a-883b-4b20-9460-3eee486516a8/audio';

  const promises = utterances.map((u) => {
    return fetchUtteranceID(u.utteranceId, `${config.public.apiBase}${basePath}`);
  });

  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(results);
};
```