# Types for Promise.all()

Tags: typescript, promise

I cannot figure out these types between the request tuple return type and `Promise.all()`. I am going insane with this.

Any ideas?

```
const createPromises = async (utteranceObject: Array<string[]>): 
  Promise<Array<[string, Blob]>> => {
  const promises = utteranceObject.map((keyValue) => {
    return buildAudioFetchRequests(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
  });
  return Promise.all<Promise<[string, Blob]>[]>(promises);
};

const buildAudioFetchRequests = (key: string, url: string): 
     [string, Promise<[string, Blob]>] => {
  return [key, useAuthenticatedFetch(url, { initialCache: false })];
};
```

[image]

Comment: You need to change `buildAudioFetchRequest` to return `Promise<[string, Blob]>`, not `[string, Promise<Blob>]`.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misconception in your code based on the variable name `promises`.

The returntype of `buildAudioFetchRequests` is not a promise, it's a tuple of a key and a promise. Awaiting that value returns the same tuple, since await is not concerned about the contents of an object or array.

Based on all the other return types, it seems that you want to await all the returned promises that are part of the tuple, so something like this instead:

```
const createPromises = async (utteranceObject: Array<string[]>): 
  Promise<Array<[string, Blob]>> => {

  // Rename this variable here
  const requests = utteranceObject.map((keyValue) => {
    return buildAudioFetchRequests(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
  });

  // Get the actual promise from the tuple
  const promises = requests.map((req) => req[1]);

  // You can even remove the explicit typing from here because it's all as intended now!
  return Promise.all(promises);
};

const buildAudioFetchRequests = (key: string, url: string): 
     [string, Promise<[string, Blob]>] => {
  return [key, useAuthenticatedFetch(url, { initialCache: false })];
};
```

---

Following Bergi's comment:

> Why even return the `key` in a tuple from `buildAudioFetchRequests` when all you do is ignore it?

If you are indeed not using the key of the return value of that function anywhere, you could also do this:

```
const createPromises = async (utteranceObject: Array<string[]>): 
  Promise<Array<[string, Blob]>> => {
  const promises = utteranceObject.map((keyValue) => {
    return buildAudioFetchRequests(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
  });

  // Remove explicit typing here
  return Promise.all(promises);
};

const buildAudioFetchRequests = (key: string, url: string): 
     // Change the returntype here
     Promise<[string, Blob]> => {

  // Change the return value here
  return useAuthenticatedFetch(url, { initialCache: false });
};
```

Comment: Why even return the `key` in a tuple from `buildAudioFetchRequests` when all you do is ignore it?

Comment: @Bergi That is a question better answered by OP, I believe! Maybe that function is used somewhere else but for such questions I rather leave all function signatures intact if that is indeed the case and instead show a way to make use of it in its current state, explaining why the solution works the way it does. Regardless, I added a note on that solution as well, thanks for the suggestion!