# How to get two arrays from one json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

i have this:

```
    var keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    var values = [11, 22, 33]

    var result = {};
    keys.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = values[i]);
    console.log(result);
```

which is the right way to push the keys ans the values back to separated arrays from json result?

```
    result = {"foo:11,"bar":22,"baz":33}
    keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    values = [11, 22, 33]
```

Comment: keys: `Object.keys(result)` and for values: `Object.values(result)`

Comment: What do you want `result` to look like in the end?

Comment: i want the arrays look like  var keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    var values = [11, 22, 33]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, for `Objects` in javascript you can use 2 useful functions called [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), you can check the documentation to see if any other function can work for you.

check the [Methods section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

```js
const result = {
  "foo": 11,
  "bar": 22,
  "baz": 33
}

const keys = Object.keys(result);
const values = Object.values(result);

console.log("here you have the keys")
console.log(keys)
console.log("here you have the values")
console.log(values)
```