# How can use my object like a array using with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import styles from './subTheme-select.module.css'
import StoreContext from '../store'

const SUB_THEME = {
  blue: 'Blue',
  yellow: 'Yellow',
  pink: 'Pink',
  purple: 'Purple',
  orange: 'Orange',
  green: 'Green'
}

function SubThemeSelect() {
  const store = useContext(StoreContext)

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {SUB_THEME.map((subTheme) => (
        <label className={styles.label}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value={subTheme}
            name={subTheme}
            checked={subTheme === store.subTheme}
            onChange={(e) => store.changeSubTheme(e.target.value)}
          />
          {SUB_THEME[subTheme]}
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SubThemeSelect
```

I want a use SUB_THEME like an array like [blue, yellow, pink, purple, orange, green]
how can I do this.

[image]

This is the error message.

How can handle that issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Comment: Can you specify if you what the keys for `'blue'` or if you want the values `'Blue'`. Many answers tell you how to get keys but i suspect you want the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `Object.keys()` function or the `Object.values`

```js
const SUB_THEME = {
  blue: 'Blue',
  yellow: 'Yellow',
  pink: 'Pink',
  purple: 'Purple',
  orange: 'Orange',
  green: 'Green'
}
//this returns the keys
const theme_keys = Object.keys(SUB_THEME)
//this returns the values
const theme_values = Object.values(SUB_THEME)
```

Then you can map them like

```
theme_keys.map( key => {/*code here*/})
theme_values.map( key => {/*code here*/})
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to map an object you need to use Object.keys which returns an array of the objects keys that you can loop over.

```
Object.keys(SUB_THEME).map((key,index) => {
 const subTheme = SUB_THEME[key]
 return (
 <label className={styles.label}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value={subTheme}
            name={subTheme}
            checked={subTheme === store.subTheme}
            onChange={(e) => store.changeSubTheme(e.target.value)}
          />
          {subTheme}
        </label>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below :

```
Object.keys(SUB_THEME).map( (key) => {
console.log(SUB_THEME[key]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object.keys(SUB_GROUPED).map(x => {
    console.log(x)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Get object keys firstly with Object.keys(SUB_THEME).