# How can I get a key from an Any type in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, types

I'm trying to figure out how to get a key from an Any type in Angular/Typescript.

For example, if some other part of the program is returning this code:

```
{
  Amy: {
         age: 7,
         grade: 2
       },
  Max: {
         age: 9,
         grade: 4
       },
  Mia: {
         age: 8,
         grade: 3
       }
}
```

Is there a way that I can put the names in an array such as:

```
[ "Amy", "Max", "Mia" ]
```

I've tried to use forEach, but the first bit of code isn't exactly an array so I'm not sure if that is on the right track at all. Is there some sort of function I can use to turn Amy into a string? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The *types* or the *values*? forEach is at runtime.

Comment: I would like to have an array of [ "Amy", "Max", "Mia" ]. My bad, I will update my post right now.

Comment: But as a *type*, at compile time, or a *value*, at runtime (in which case TypeScript isn't really relevant - and either way Angular isn't)?

Comment: Based on the answer, this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys - please do research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Object.keys()

```js
let obj = {
  Amy: {
         age: 7,
         grade: 2
       },
  Max: {
         age: 9,
         grade: 4
       },
  Mia: {
         age: 8,
         grade: 3
       }
}
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to use anything from Angular for this you can use plain JavaScript functionality.  Just grab the keys from the object with `Object.keys`

```js
const myObject:any = {
  Amy: {
         age: 7,
         grade: 2
       },
  Max: {
         age: 9,
         grade: 4
       },
  Mia: {
         age: 8,
         grade: 3
       }
}
const names:Array<string> = Object.keys(myObject);
console.log(names);
```