# Get the id of an object in a json request?

Tags: javascript, json, api, object

So I have to get the first object of this list:

```
{
"2489": {
    "status": {
        "idstatus": "3",
        "status": "Sold"
    }
},

"2490": {
    "status": {
        "idstatus": "3",
        "status": "Sold"
    }
}
```

}

I don't know beforehand the IDs ['2489'] and ['2490']. Sometimes it responses only one of these IDs, sometimes 3 or more.

How can I get like ['2490'].status.idstatus without knowing ['2490']?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using `Object.values` and `map` or if you need the key you can use `Object.entries`

```js
const data = {
"2489": {
    "status": {
        "idstatus": "3",
        "status": "Sold"
    }
},

"2490": {
    "status": {
        "idstatus": "3",
        "status": "Sold"
    }
}
}

const statusIds = Object.values(data).map(d => d.status.idstatus)
console.log(statusIds)

const statusIdAndKey = Object.entries(data).map(([k, d]) => [k, d.status.idstatus])
console.log(statusIdAndKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. If you're running a modern JS environment, you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Assuming your JSON response object is a variable named `res`, you can construct a dynamic array of IDs like this:

```js
const ids = Object.keys(res) // ["2489", "2490", ...]
```

If you don't care about the IDs at all and want an array of all the inner objects, try this:

```js
const items = Object.values(res) // [ { "status" : ... }, ... ]
```