# Convery JS Object to array - keep key & value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to convert an object (updatedConfig) to an array (configArray), while maintaining the same structure (and avoid further nesting).

I have tried declaring a new array const and using Object.entries to push the keys & values.
I am able to get the keys but am having trouble figuring out how to achieve the nesting of array.

```
const configArray = [];
    
    Object.entries(updatedConfig).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        configArray.push(key);     
    })
```

Here is the object in question:
[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you're looking for?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) For code like that shown, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`

Comment: For the question, there is an `Object.keys(obj)` method that gets just the keys, no need to get the entries and pull just the key...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys), specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310101/215552).

Comment: I need the array's associated with the keys too

Comment: @Jordan Could you update the question to include what the output should look like? I don't understand what structure you're hoping to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this using `Object.entries` and `Array.map`

```js
const configObject = {
 key1: 'value',
 key2: 1,
 key3: [1, 2, 3]

}

const configArray = Object.entries(configObject).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))

console.log(configArray)
```