# How to retrieve first object's property names of an object array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object array with below structure and I need to get first object's property names alone from this array and not values. My result should only have `["Name" , "Account", "Status"]`.

I tried below lines of code but the result was not as expected. I am getting the result along with index 0. Can someone guide me here to achieve the result.

```
tempVar=   [
      {
        "Name"    : "A1",
        "Account" : "Dom",
        "Status"  : "A"
      },
      {
        "Name"    : "A5",
        "IntAccount" : "Int",
        "Status"  : "A"
      },
      {
        "Name"    : "A2",
        "LclAccount" : "Lcl",
        "Status"  : "A"
      },
      {
        "Name"    : "A4",
        "UnknownAccount" : "UA",
        "Status"  : "A"
      }
    ];
let propNames: Array<any> = [];
tempVar= tempVar.splice(0,1);
for (let el of tempVar) 
{
  propNames.push(Object.keys(el))
}
console.log(propNames);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Comment: _"I am getting the result along with index 0"_ - because you're putting it in another array? What did you _think_ `propNames.push(Object.keys(el))` was doing? If you wanted them to be separate items, maybe `propNames.push(...Object.keys(el))`, but then given that you're looping over _one single thing_ that's just... `propNames = Object.keys(el)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it.

To get the first element, index `tempVar` with square brackets: `tempVar[0]`.

Then, to get the keys, just call `Object.keys()` on it:

```
const propNames = Object.keys(tempVar[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following lines of code:

```
let propNames: Array<any> = [];
tempVar= tempVar.splice(0,1);
for (let key in tempVar) 
{
  propNames.push(key)
}
console.log(propNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let propNames: Array<any> = [];
for (const key of Object.keys(tempVar[0])) {
  propNames.push(key)
}
console.log(propNames);
```