# How to loop and display object key?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object as following below:

```
scores = {"grade1":
               {"math":"120","english":"100"},
           "grade2":
               {"math":"50","english":"50"},
           "grade3":
                {"math":"90","english":"70"}
          }
```

I want to display object key with `*ngFor` to look like this:

```
Field: grade1 
Field: grade2 
Field: grade3
```

I tried using `Object.keys(scores)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBoCcCmEYF4YG8BQM-4LwCIBzBAQwBMkBGIgLl0Of0yIFtyoALBomgEwAGIgBoiSMCQA2ASwi96-ISIC+opi3ykK1AQ01aCbTjz4BWEeMkz5iopaLrDWnVSQBmA0ZYmu9gE4rCSk5BT4AdjUXFlVsGMJQSBBpJAA6aRASAAoAeQAjACskYCg0gGskAE8IbPgQZAgASiagA  it does work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array of object's keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763125/get-array-of-objects-keys)

Comment: yes, but if i want them as an index key and loop, it doesn't work.

Comment: But you want to loop it on `html` using `*ngFor`, correct?

Comment: @viiii Ah my apologies, I didn't know what ngFor was.

Comment: yes i want to loop in html

Comment: it doesn't need to be an array, use keyvalue pipe to transform it

Comment: @traynor Didn't know we could do things this way, it's interesting.

Comment: @manjirosano well, it says a lot about angular..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop object keys, transform object to key value pairs with [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of scores | keyvalue">
Field: {{item.key}}

<br>
full object: {{item.key}}:{{item.value | json}}

</div>
```

and you can get object values via `{{item.value}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (let grade in scores) {
  console.log(`Field: ${grade}`);
}
```