# AngularJS ng-repeat handle empty list case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

I thought this would be a very common thing, but I couldn't find how to handle it in AngularJS. Let's say I have a list of events and want to output them with AngularJS, then that's pretty easy:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="event in events">{{event.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

But how do I handle the case when the list is empty? I want to have a message box in place where the list is with something like "No events" or similar. The only thing that would come close is the `ng-switch` with `events.length` (how do I check if empty when an object and not an array?), but is that really the only option I have?

Comment: @Artem's answer is good (+1).  Here's a google group discussion that uses a filter, for reference/comparison: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/wR06cN5oVBQ/discussion

Answer (score 571, accepted):

You can use [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow).

```
<li ng-show="!events.length">No events</li>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/C29As/).

Or you can use [ngHide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide)

```
<li ng-hide="events.length">No events</li>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/C29As/37/).

For object you can test [Object.keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921193/457375).

Comment: Indeed @ArtemAndreev. When "events" is an empty array, it returns true even though the array is empty

Comment: I think there's a problem with Object.keys: http://jsfiddle.net/J9b5z/, how would you handle this?

Comment: nh-show worked id my case but it doesnt update the state when I put a filter in and nothing returned. Also the object appears on first load and disappears when the repeat process done on page load.

Comment: @Dani try adding a function to your controller that performs the test.  You can then just invoked the directive with `ng-hide="hasEvents()"`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. However, I hoped there would be a more elegant way without "polluting" the controller.

Comment: What if I use loads of filter in ng-repeat?

Comment: As @RobJuurlink pointed out this won't work as expected. I think **ng-show="events.length < 1"** or **ng-hide="events.length > 1"** would be a better solution.

Answer (score 372):

And if you want to use this with a filtered list here's a neat trick:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems  = (items | filter:keyword)">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
<div ng-hide="filteredItems.length">No items found</div>
```

Comment: Very useful.  Typo though with "filteredFragments".

Comment: Sweet! The expression inside ng-repeat looks strange though. Any chance you could explain it? Thanks!!

Comment: @MKSafi, it is creating a new variable on the scope called `filteredItems` and setting its value to `(items | filter:keyword)` - in other words, the array returned by the filter

Comment: YES! Ninja plus points! This saves angular from evaluating a complex filter twice!

Comment: This duplicates the filtered list though, right? Could cause slowness depending on how big your list is and what's in it. Or does Angular already save the filtered list in memory, so now you're just saving a reference to it in the scope so you can access it later?

Comment: What's the scope of the variable that's created? I'd like to use it to disable a div that contains the list. The contain div doesn't seem to be able to access the variable.

Comment: Also, there seem to be some limitations around this with multiple filters, like `"face in filteredFaces = faces|filter:{deleted: true} | orderBy:'text'` but I agree with everyone, this is a fabulous trick.

Comment: Nice trick, but I'm curious why the whole <ul> instead of the <li>-Element is repeated here?

Answer (score 29):

You might want to check out the [angular-ui directive](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-if) `ui-if` if you just want to remove the `ul` from the DOM when the list is empty:

```
<ul ui-if="!!events.length">
    <li ng-repeat="event in events">{{event.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Feels cleaner than just hiding it.

Comment: @Mortimer: so in this case do we need angular-ui?

Comment: you can use `ng-hide` without angular-ui, but it will just hide the node, it won't remove it from the DOM tree. With angular-ui's `ui-if` directive, it will remove the DOM node.
So, you need to at least add the `ui-if` directive from the angular-ui code to your own code.

Comment: newest angular has `ng-if` included!

Comment: Note that `ng-if` is creating a new scope, where `ng-hide` isn't. This might cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 29):

With the newer versions of angularjs the correct answer to this question is to use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-if="list.length === 0">( No items in this list yet! )</li>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

This solution will not flicker when the list is about to download either because the list has to be defined and with a length of 0 for the message to display.

Here is a plunker to show it in use: http://plnkr.co/edit/in7ha1wTlpuVgamiOblS?p=preview

Tip: You can also show a loading text or spinner:

```
  <li ng-if="!list">( Loading... )</li>
```

Answer (score 23):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:keyword as filteredItems">
        ...
    </li>
    <li ng-if="filteredItems.length===0">
        No items found
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is similar to @Konrad 'ktoso' Malawski but slightly easier to remember.

Tested with Angular 1.4

Comment: You mean `ng-if='!filteredItems.length'`

Comment: How do you do this with multiple filters?

Comment: @Jordash Just keep piping them  `item in items | filter: ... | filter: ...`

Comment: A nice, further refinement is `<li ng-if="!filteredItems.length">`

Comment: This is great. I have been using a lot dirtyer method before like `item in (filteredItems = (items | filter: someFilter))`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different approach using CSS instead of JavaScript/AngularJS.

CSS:

```
.emptymsg {
  display: list-item;
}

li + .emptymsg {
  display: none;
}
```

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems"> ... </li>
    <li class="emptymsg">No items found</li>
</ul>
```

If the list is empty, <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">, etc. will get commented out and will become a comment instead of a li element.

Comment: Question says "I want to have a message box in place where the list is". I also think it's disadvantageous to separate the logic into s stylesheet. Hard to maintain and asking for trouble.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, I think using CSS is an advantage because the logic is very simple and easy to maintain, the CSS is reusable for other lists, and it doesn't rely on JavaScript. No additional listeners  or watchers are needed. The message could be styled to look like a box, I just didn't to keep the answer simple.

Comment: A few months late, granted, but I agree with Miriam, I think this answer is genius.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this ng-switch:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="friendsCtrl">
  <label>Search: </label><input ng-model="searchText" type="text">
  <div ng-init="filtered = (friends | filter:searchText)">
  <h3>'Found '{{(friends | filter:searchText).length}} friends</h3>
  <div ng-switch="(friends | filter:searchText).length">
    <span class="ng-empty" ng-switch-when="0">No friends</span>
    <table ng-switch-default>
      <thead>  
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as` keyword to refer a collection under a `ng-repeat` element:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:category | filter:query as res">
        <td>{{task.id}}</td>
        <td>{{task.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="res.length === 0">
        <td colspan="2">no results</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually use ng-show

```
<li ng-show="variable.length"></li>
```

where variable you define for example

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
   <li ng-show="product.length">show something</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-if because this is not render in html page and you dont see your html tag in inspect...

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="items.length > 0">
    <li>{{item}}<li>
</ul>
<div class="alert alert-info">there is no items!</div>
```