# Angular if ng-repeat multi filter is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lets say I have multiple filters in my `ng-repeat` like so:

```
input.search(ng-model="filter", placeholder="Search...")

ul.list
  li(ng-if="things.length === 0") It looks like we don't have any things.
  li(ng-repeat="thing in things | orderBy:'name' | filter: search")
    span {{ thing.name }}
```

Right now, if I initially have no `things`, then I receive the message saying so. But if I filter by something which yields no results, it does not display the message, which I understand.

My question is, how do you implement a multi-filter `ng-repeat` and display a message when the collection or filter yields no results?

I was messing with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593018/1842294) to no avail. My attempt:

```
thing in filteredThings = thing | orderBy: 'name' | filter: search
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, syntax was a little off:

```
(ng-repeat="thing in filteredThings = (things | orderBy:'name' | filter: search"))

li(ng-if="filteredThings.length === 0") It looks like we don't have any things.
```

Comment: So my attempt failed miserably (example updated). I tried the above but am getting errors. The bigger question is where does `filteredThings` come from? `things` is a collection in scope, does `filteredThings` have to exist as well? Or is that created on the fly?

Comment: @Seth - It's created on the fly - what errors are you getting?

Comment: I put the close parenthesis outside the `ng-repeat` attribute... All's well in the cosmos. Thanks for your help!