# Double loop, display no results if nothing to dispay

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJs, i have a double loop to display data, and a filter by year.

When, for a given year, i have no results, i want to display the message "No results...", but because of the double loop, i'm not able to get it to work

Here is a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/OSWSyXk8bnvmj1rFwHJ0?p=preview

The div i want to display when

```
<div ng-if="personnes.length < 1" class="noresults">No RESULTS</div>
```

To see an example with no results, choose "2013-2014" in the Year dropdown

Thanks a lot

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18593018/5246

Comment: I don't see how this link can help ?

Comment: Could you provide a more readable example? First thing to notice - `personnes` is not an array so `personnes.length` won't work as you expect.

Comment: What's not readable so i can improve my plunker ?

Comment: I updated my plunker, personnes is now an array, but it's still not working as personnes.length always return the same number, and doesn't change when i change the filter value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not so pretty as I would like, but anyways. You could update your html as follows:

```
<div ng-if="filterArray(resultsPersonnes).length < 1 && $first" class="noresults">No RESULTS</div>
```

and in your controller create new function:

```
$scope.filterArray = function(resultsPersonnes) {
    return resultsPersonnes.filter(function(prop) { return prop.fraiss[0].annee == $scope.annee.id; });
}
```

So basically this just repeats what angular does for you in `ng-repeat` with filters. See updated [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/P9xdt6KLNY53xQBWRce1?p=preview).