# AngularJs : ng-repeat with ng-if, repeating more than it should in ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to have a list of data that is filtered by its defined property (monitored), i can't just do :

```
ng-if="project.monitored"
```

since i need to count unmonitored ones.

for the example i simplified the data returned from getProjects(), which is normally :

```
this.projects = {
    "owned": [
        {
            "name": "project-1",
            "monitored": true
        },
        {
            "name": "project-2",
            "monitored": true
        }
    ],
    "John Doe": [
        {
            "name": "project-3",
            "monitored": true
        },
        {
            "name": "project-4",
            "monitored": false
        }
    ]
};
```

I'll iterate through this.projects.owner at first then through the rest later in the template. Total of unmonitored here would be equal to 1.

So i guess i can't use such kind of [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340095/angular-js-ng-repeat-handle-empty-list-case#answer-18593018)

---

**EXAMPLE :**

template

```
<div ng-init="getProjects()">
    <div ng-if="vm.isMonitored(project.name)" ng-repeat="project in vm.projects">{{ project.name }}</div>  
</div>
```

controller :

```
getProjects(){

    console.log('init');

    this.projects = {
        {
            "name": "project-1",
            "monitored": true
        },
        {
            "name": "project-2",
            "monitored": true
        }
    };

}

isMonitored(name) {

    console.log('Name :'+name);

    return true;

}
```

template is correctly displaying 2 results :

project-1
project-2

but the console.log :

```
init
dashboard.controller.js?e45c:217 Name :project-1
dashboard.controller.js?e45c:217 Name :project-2
dashboard.controller.js?e45c:217 Name :project-1
dashboard.controller.js?e45c:217 Name :project-2
dashboard.controller.js?e45c:217 Name :project-1
dashboard.controller.js?e45c:217 Name :project-2
```

So i can't understand why i have so many duplicates from console.log while the result displayed on the template is correct.

Therefore if i count anything in ng-if, the result would be wrong. Why? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each digest cycle, AngularJS will reevaluate the registered watchers (so your `vm.isMonitored(project.name)`). This is why your console show many times the log.

When you use a `ng-if`, the value used must be a boolean, or a method returning a boolean. You can't do business work in this method, because of the mecanism of AngularJS. To be good, your view should be :

```html
<div ng-if="project.monitored" ng-repeat="project in vm.projects">{{ project.name }}</div>
```

Or even better, you could filter your collection in the controller to optimize the `ng-repeat` work.