# How to loop multidimensional map in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am unable to loop through the multidimensional map, I have a sample map below,
here known values are its key. i.e 'one', 'two'.. Now how can I find out the inner values of it. I would like to get **a,b** from **one** and **c,d** from **two**

```
{
  one: {
    a: {
      id: '6',
      name: 'abc',
      age: '30',
      place: 'xyz'
    },
    b: {
      id: '7',
      name: 'def',
      age: '31',
      place: 'xyx'
    },
  },
  two: {
    c: {
      id: '8',
      name: 'ghi',
      age: '32',
      place: 'xxz'
    },
    d: {
      id: '9',
      name: 'ghi',
      age: '33',
      place: 'yyx'
    }
  }
}
```

It would be really helpful if I get any solution for this..Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find keys of a hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912/how-to-find-keys-of-a-hash)

Comment: you can use them like json [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure](example)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
  return Object.keys(obj[key])
})
```

`Object.keys` return the keys of the object, and you can map those keys using the `map` method. The key name is passed to the map and it return the keys of each object stored on each keys. It's not so clear why you need that as you kind of loose the parent and children nodes while doing this.

Comment: Object.entries() returns [key, value] pairs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries