# Vue JS - Dynamically add class to one element then remove class to siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am new in using Vue.

I have a JS like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        nav1: true,
        nav2: false,
        nav3: false
    },
    methods: {
        activatedThis: function(n){
            if( n === 'nav2' )
            {
               this.nav1 = false;
               this.nav3 = false;
               this.nav2 = true;
            }
            else if( n === 'nav3' )
            //And so on...
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
   <h1 @click="activatedThis('nav1')" v-bind:class="{ active: nav1 }">Navigation 1</h1>
   <h1 @click="activatedThis('nav2')" v-bind:class="{ active: nav2 }">Navigation 2</h1>
   <h1 @click="activatedThis('nav3')" v-bind:class="{ active: nav3 }">Navigation 3</h1>
</div>
```

I want to make my method dynamic.. I am thinking to loop the `this`. But since I don't know a lot about Vue yet... **Is there a pure Vue way to this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your code like following to make it more concise:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        navs: {
           nav1: true,
           nav2: false,
           nav3: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        activatedThis: function(nav){
               this.navs.nav1 = nav === "nav1";
               this.navs.nav3 = nav === "nav2";
               this.navs.nav2 = nav === "nav3";
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <h1 v-for="(nav, index) in Object.keys(navs)" @click="activatedThis(nav)" v-bind:class="{ 'active': navs[nav] }">Navigation {{index}}</h1>
</div>
```

Related Links:

- [How can I find the keys of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912/how-to-find-keys-of-a-hash)
- [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for)